# How can I sort the columns of a large data frame based on specific criteria?

Tags: r, sorting, character, alphabetical

I would like to sort the columns of a large dataframe (around 14000 variables) based on a specific rationale.

The column names have the following structure (Condition_Sleepstage_Parameter_Electrode_Nightpart):

```
 [1] "Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour"          "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour"         
  [3] "Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour"        "Book_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour"          
  [5] "Book_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour"           "Book_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour"
```

R has the columns ordered in a purely alphabetical structure but I would like to have them in a logical order based on the following system:

First, variables should be presented in blocks per parameter. (order: "negLengthLoc", "posLength", "wholeLength", "negPeak", "nbnegPeaks", "initialMeannegSlope", "finalMeannegSlope", "initialMaxnegslope", "finalMaxnegslope", "posPeak", "nbposPeaks", "initialMeannposSlope", "finalMeanposSlope", "initialMaxposSlope", "PeaktoPeak", "Number", "Density")

Within these blocks, the highest order hierarchy should be due to Condition. (order: "Adapt", "NoFilter", "Filter", "Book").

Thereafter, the next hierarchy should be defined by Electrode. (order: "F3", "Fz", "F4", "C3", "Cz", "C4", "P3", "Pz", "P4", "O1", "O2").

Thereafter by Nightpart (order:"firstHour", "firstQuarter", "secondQuarter", "thirdQuarter", "fourthQuarter", "wholeNight") and lastly by Sleepstage ("order: "N2", "N3", "NREM").

The resulting order should look like:

```
[1] "Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_F3_firstHour"          "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_F3_firstHour"
[3] "Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_F3_firstHour"          "Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_F3_firstQuarter"
[5] "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_F3_firstQuarter"          "Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_F3_firstQuarter"
[7] "Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_F3_secondQuarter"          "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_F3_secondQuarter"
[9] "Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_F3_secondQuarter"          "Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_F3_thirdQuarter"
[11] "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_F3_thirdQuarter"          "Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_F3_thirdQuarter"
[13] "Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_F3_fourthQuarter"          "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_F3_fourthQuarter"
[15] "Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_F3_fourthQuarter"          "Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_F3_wholeNight"
[17] "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_F3_wholeNight"           "Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_F3_wholeNight"
[19] "Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_Fz_firstHour"           "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_Fz_firstHour"
...
```

I hope that someone can help me, if there are any further questions then I am of course happy to provide more information!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to SO! You have a lot of information in your column names. Is it necessary that this information is stored as the column name? Working with the data would be easier if you store the information in separate columns (e.g. one column for `parameter`, one for `Condition` and so on), following the principle of tidy data: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Since this data is further distributed to students who will work with SPSS, it is necessary to have the data in this 'extreme' wide format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illustrating with the `mtcars` data, one can reorder the columns in a data frame by creating a vector with the the desired order, and using this in the column specification with the `[` form of the extract operator.

First, we'll use `colnames()` to extract the original order of the columns and print them

```
theNames <- colnames(mtcars)
theNames

> theNames
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

Next, we'll move all of the integer columns to the left side of the data frame by creating a `reorderedNames` vector and using it with `[`.

```
reorderedNames <- c("cyl" , "vs" ,  "am" ,  "gear" ,"carb","disp" ,
                     "drat", "wt" ,  "qsec", "mpg")
mtcars[,reorderedNames]
```

...and the first few rows of output:

```
> mtcars[,reorderedNames]
                    cyl vs am gear carb  disp drat    wt  qsec  mpg
Mazda RX4             6  0  1    4    4 160.0 3.90 2.620 16.46 21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag         6  0  1    4    4 160.0 3.90 2.875 17.02 21.0
Datsun 710            4  1  1    4    1 108.0 3.85 2.320 18.61 22.8
Hornet 4 Drive        6  1  0    3    1 258.0 3.08 3.215 19.44 21.4
Hornet Sportabout     8  0  0    3    2 360.0 3.15 3.440 17.02 18.7
Valiant               6  1  0    3    1 225.0 2.76 3.460 20.22 18.1
Duster 360            8  0  0    3    4 360.0 3.21 3.570 15.84 14.3
Merc 240D             4  1  0    4    2 146.7 3.69 3.190 20.00 24.4
```

### Automating this process for a large data frame

In the OP, the question references a data frame with a large number of columns. In order to extend this process to automate the sorting of columns, there are at least two major approaches.

1. Process the column names from the data frame in a manner that allows one to sort the column names in the desired order, or
2. Create a narrow format tidy data set by using `pivot_longer()` to split the column names into the required grouping variables.

We'll use data from the OP to illustrate approach 1.

```
columnName <- c("Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour","Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour",         
"Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour","Book_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour",          
"Book_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour","Book_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour")
splitCols <- strsplit(columnName,"_")

results <- lapply(splitCols,function(x){
     parameter <- x[3]
     condition <- x[1]
     electrode <- x[4]
     nightpart <- x[5]
     sleepstage <- x[2]
     data.frame(parameter,condition,electrode,nightpart,sleepstage)
})

colsData <- do.call(rbind,results)
# add original column names back into data
colsData <- cbind(columnName,colsData)
# convert to factors, specifying the factor order for sorting
conditionOrder <- c("Adapt", "NoFilter", "Filter", "Book")
parameterOrder <- c("negLengthLoc", "posLength", "wholeLength", "negPeak", "nbnegPeaks", 
                    "initialMeannegSlope", "finalMeannegSlope", "initialMaxnegslope", 
                    "finalMaxnegslope", "posPeak", "nbposPeaks", "initialMeannposSlope",
                    "finalMeanposSlope", "initialMaxposSlope", "PeaktoPeak", "Number", "Density")
electrodeOrder <- c("F3", "Fz", "F4", "C3", "Cz", "C4", "P3", "Pz", "P4", "O1", "O2")
nightpartOrder <- c("firstHour", "firstQuarter", "secondQuarter", "thirdQuarter", "fourthQuarter", "wholeNight") 
sleepstageOrder <- c("N2", "N3", "NREM")
colsData$condition <- factor(colsData$condition,levels = conditionOrder,ordered = TRUE)
colsData$parameter <- factor(colsData$parameter,levels = parameterOrder,ordered = TRUE)
colsData$electrode <- factor(colsData$electrode,levels = electrodeOrder,ordered = TRUE)
colsData$nightpart <- factor(colsData$nightpart,levels = nightpartOrder,ordered = TRUE)
colsData$sleepstage <- factor(colsData$sleepstage,levels = sleepstageOrder,ordered = TRUE)

# finally, sort by factors & create a vector for column number
library(dplyr)
colsData <- arrange(colsData,condition,parameter,electrode,nightpart,sleepstage)
colsData$colId <- 1:nrow(colsData)
colsData
```

...and the output:

```
> colsData
                            columnName    parameter condition electrode nightpart
1   Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour negLengthLoc     Adapt        C3 firstHour
2   Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour negLengthLoc     Adapt        C3 firstHour
3 Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour negLengthLoc     Adapt        C3 firstHour
4    Book_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour negLengthLoc      Book        C3 firstHour
5    Book_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour negLengthLoc      Book        C3 firstHour
6  Book_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour negLengthLoc      Book        C3 firstHour
  sleepstage colId
1         N2     1
2         N3     2
3       NREM     3
4         N2     4
5         N3     5
6       NREM     6
>
```

At this point we can use `colsData$columnName` to order the original data frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not really solve my problem since it would require an ordering vector containing the desired order. However, my problem is that I really do not want to order these 14.000 somewhat variable names by hand :-/

Comment: @ChristopherHöhn - Thanks for the feedback, Christopher. See my updated answer for an automated solution using the data you included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the column name into the different parts that it consists of. That is done with `str_split` from the `stringr` package. It produces a list with an entry for every column name, every entry is a character vector with the different parts.
To create new columns with the different parts, I use `map_chr` from the `purrr` package to access the corresponding entry for every column name. Then, the columns are arranged. To achieve your desired order, convert the characters to `factor` and specify the order with the `levels`. The new order of the columns is represented by the column `rowid`:

```
old_order <- data.frame(col_names = c("Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour",          "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour",        
               "Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour",        "Book_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour",          
               "Book_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour",           "Book_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour",
               "Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_Fz_firstHour",           "Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_Fz_firstHour"))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

splitted_names <- str_split(old_order$col_names, "_")

new_order <- old_order %>% 
  tibble::rowid_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(Condition = purrr::map_chr(splitted_names, `[`, 1),
         Sleepstage = purrr::map_chr(splitted_names, `[`, 2),
         Parameter = purrr::map_chr(splitted_names, `[`, 3),
         Electrode = purrr::map_chr(splitted_names, `[`, 4),
         Nightpart = purrr::map_chr(splitted_names, `[`, 5)) %>% 
  arrange(factor(Parameter, levels = c("negLengthLoc", "posLength", "wholeLength", "negPeak", "nbnegPeaks", "initialMeannegSlope", "finalMeannegSlope", "initialMaxnegslope", "finalMaxnegslope", "posPeak", "nbposPeaks", "initialMeannposSlope", "finalMeanposSlope", "initialMaxposSlope", "PeaktoPeak", "Number", "Density")),
          factor(Condition, levels = c("Adapt", "NoFilter", "Filter", "Book")),
          factor(Electrode, levels = c("F3", "Fz", "F4", "C3", "Cz", "C4", "P3", "Pz", "P4", "O1", "O2")),
          factor(Nightpart, levels = c("firstHour", "firstQuarter", "secondQuarter", "thirdQuarter", "fourthQuarter", "wholeNight")),
          factor(Sleepstage, levels = c("N2", "N3", "NREM"))) %>% 
  pull(rowid)

old_order$col_names[new_order]
[1] Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_Fz_firstHour   Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_Fz_firstHour   Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour  
[4] Adapt_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour   Adapt_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour Book_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour   
[7] Book_N3_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour    Book_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour 
8 Levels: Adapt_N2_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour ... Book_NREM_negLengthLoc_C3_firstHour
```

Now that you already have the information separated into different columns, I recommend you to bring the complete data set into a [tidy (long) format](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html).